# Struggling with parsing json dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am pulling an API response that I am using json.loads to convert to a dictionary and I am trying to parse specific key value pairs out to append a python list.

I am converting the API response using json.loads

```
def get_user_id(user):
    get_user_data = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/user/" + user)
    decode_user_data = get_user_data.content.decode("UTF-8")
    user_data = json.loads(decode_user_data)
```

Then I am attempting to parse specific key values out of user_data and append that information into my dictionary user_ids

```
    for i in user_data:
        user_ids.append({'username': i["username"], 'user_id': i["user_id"]})
```

But I am receiving a TypeError when attempting this.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

when I run

```
print(user_data["username"])
print(user_data["user_id"])
```

I receive the desired response

Output of user_data

```
{'verification': None, 'username': 'zeustrl', 'user_id': '766368574179770368', 'token': None, 'summoner_region': None, 'summoner_name': None, 'solicitable': None, 'real_name': None, 'phone': None, 'pending': None, 'notifications': None, 'metadata': None, 'is_bot': False, 'email': None, 'display_name': 'ZeusTRL', 'deleted': None, 'data_updated': None, 'currencies': None, 'created': None, 'cookies': None, 'avatar': 'f64d0b7a8d0e6fbf0d7856185875d972'}
```

Comment: as an aside, your function can simply be `return requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/user/" + user).json()`

Comment: user_ids is a list, i typo'd

Comment: in any case, JSON has nothing to do with your question. You are working with a *dictionary*. Or some other python data structure. It isn't JSON any more. You need to give us an example of what that data actually is. If it *is* a dictionary, then `for i in user_data:` will iterate over the *keys* of the dictionary. But we can only speculate about what is going wrong without a [mcve].

Comment: `user_data` is a dictionary if `print(user_data["username"])` works. Thus `for i in user_data` works over a list of keys (strings like "username") of that dictionary and thus `i["username"]` does not make sense.

Comment: Please provide an example of `user_data` otherwise it will be hard to provide a working solution.

Comment: I added the output of user_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because iterating over a dictionary returns the keys, as strings.

So on the first iteration of your loop, `i` is the string "verification", and your code tries to do `"verification"["username"]` which is nonsense.

But because `user_data` is a single dictionary, I don't understand why you are even using a for loop in the first place.

You can just refer to the exact fields you need, without any loop at all:

```
user_data["username"]
user_data["user_id"]
```

A for loop can be used to iterate over a *list* of dictionaries (which is not the case here because you only have one dict), or if you don't know ahead of time which key(s) you want and so you need to look at them all (which again is not the case here because you already know which keys you need -- "username" and "user_id".)

What is the point of the for loop?

Comment: So if I remove the i from the user_ids.append line it just appends "username": ["username"] into user_ids without the actual values

Comment: This is the output of user_ids when I remove the I from that line

[{'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']},{'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}, {'username': ['username'], 'user_id': ['user_id']}

Comment: @zeus I have updated this answer, based on the output you gave.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Given the data structure you provided as `user_data`:

```
# Split to mutliple lines for visibility.

user_data = {
    'verification': None,
    'username': 'zeustrl',
    'user_id': '766368574179770368',
    'token': None,
    'summoner_region': None,
    'summoner_name': None,
    'solicitable': None,
    'real_name': None,
    'phone': None,
    'pending': None,
    'notifications': None,
    'metadata': None,
    'is_bot': False,
    'email': None,
    'display_name':
    'ZeusTRL',
    'deleted': None,
    'data_updated': None,
    'currencies': None,
    'created': None,
    'cookies': None,
    'avatar': 'f64d0b7a8d0e6fbf0d7856185875d972'
}
```

`user_data` is a single user entry in the form of a Python dictionary. By performing the iteration over the dictionary the way you have and printing `i` instead, like so:

```
for i in user_data:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
verification
username
user_id
token
summoner_region
summoner_name
solicitable
real_name
phone
pending
notifications
metadata
is_bot
email
display_name
deleted
data_updated
currencies
created
cookies
avatar
```

You can now see that `i` is only ever the string `key` portion of each dictionary `key: value` pair. By executing `user_ids.append({'username': i["username"], 'user_id': i["user_id"]})` as you have, you are indexing *strings*, not the dictionary. For example, the first iteration would resolve to:

```
user_ids.append({'username': "username"["username"], 'user_id': "username"["user_id"]})
```

This will give you an error, as you can not index a string with a string.

## Solution

Given the function you provided, what you'd actually want to do is the follow:

```
def get_user_id(user):
    get_user_data = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/user/" + user)
    decode_user_data = get_user_data.content.decode("UTF-8")
    user_data = json.loads(decode_user_data)

    return { "user_id": user_data["user_id"], "username": user_data["username"] }
```

There's really no need to iterate over the dictionary that is returned from parsing the response, you simply need to index the dictionary directly for "username" and return that value.

If you want to append that entry to a list, all you have to do now is:

```
user_ids.append(get_user_id(user))
```